# Simple Java field injection with Micronaut what's the missing step(s)?

Tags: java, dependency-injection, jsr330, micronaut

I am not sure *yet* if I'm on the wrong track or not.  There is an example on the [Micronaut Getting Started](https://docs.micronaut.io/latest/guide/index.html#beans) page for a V8 Engine and injecting a Vehicle.

- [Defining Beans](https://docs.micronaut.io/latest/guide/index.html#beans) (often used Engine interface example)

With that example in mind.  What is the most straightforward way to implement "Model A" with Micronaut using Java?  If there's no direct approach, what is the closest hands-off method with Micronaut?

My simple vision of vanilla field injection stepping-on with such an example is as so (using Java), I'm labelling it "Model A" ...

**Model A**

```
  import io.micronaut.context.*

  public class MyApp {                        // (A)

      @Inject 
      Vehicle vehicle;


      public void runApp( String... args ){

         println( vehicle.start() )
      }

      public static main( String... args ){

          //   whatever set-up and steps need   // (B)
          //   for auto-inject / auto-wiring.

          MyApp body = new MyApp( args  );

          body.runApp();                       // (C)
      }
  }
```

Where the annotation processor uses provides an instance of the `@Singleton` `Vehicle` in this example.  Or creates a new instance in the case of non-singleton-s.

Either way the result of the process *would be* that I don't need to write code to 'instantiate' the code or find a factory to do so explicitly.

The example itself goes on to demonstrate the method I'll label "Model B"  (using Groovy)...

**Model B**

```
  import io.micronaut.context.*
    ...
  Vehicle vehicle = BeanContext.run().getBean(Vehicle)

  println( vehicle.start() )
```

Which in fact is MORE typing than just writing:

```
  Vehicle vehicle = new Vehicle();

      //    OR

  Vehicle vehicle = Vehicle.getInstance();
```

With some libraries you need to initialise the scopes or context, I see that.  The question boils donw to what must I do to inject Vehicle as shown in my code.

I made a `@Singleton` and tried to `@Inject` the field.  The reference is NULL.  I then made a `@Provider`and set a break point. That isn't called.

- can I do "Model A"?
- If yes, what needs to happen?

I've scanned lots of examples doing great things. I'd love to get into those fancy things too.  Right now I'm in the basement looking for a way up to the ground floor.  Many thanks for you guidance.

Comment: It looks like you are using the groovy `Singleton` annotation instead of javax `Singleton` annotation...

Comment: For Model A, several things are unclear.  In `MyApp` you have a `main` method, but it isn't `static` so you won't be able to run it as a real `main`.  Assuming that is mistake in your example, the next problem is that you are trying to reference an instance field from a `static` method, which is not allowed and nonsensical.  Separate from all of that, you are using `@Inject` in a class which doesn't look like it is a bean, so it won't be subjected to DI.

Comment: @SaschaFrinken ...  Nope, `import javax.inject.Inject;` and `import javax.inject.Singleton;`

Comment: @JeffScottBrown ... I will change the name of the method.  It is NOT a static.  Key method is `runApp( String... args )`

Comment: @JeffScottBrown ... Thanks for the comment about "beans".  Now that I have had time to test a few things and read _more_ I am _imagining_  that some expansion / explanation for  of the remark: " `

Comment: (_continued_...)  _of the_ remark: "_`you are using @Inject in a class which doesn't look like it is a bean, so it won't be subjected to DI`_"; Is the information the question seeks. The referenced: `Engine` example  (_but_) is a direct quote from the Micronaut documentation on: **[3.1 Defining beans](https://docs.micronaut.io/latest/guide/index.html#beans)**  (latest).  The project describes `@Singleton` _is-a_ bean.  This is an example of an _assumed_ understanding commonly seen in documents --  Your insight will probably unlock a solution.  Insights welcome.

Comment: Beans are only auto injected into other beans.  In your case there will be a `Vehicle` bean but there will not be a `MyApp` bean.  In `MyApp` you have a `Vehicle` property that is marked with `@Inject`.  `@Inject` is only relevant in beans that are subjected to dependency injection.  Only beans are subjected to dependency injection.  You don't have a `MyApp` bean, so no `MyApp` will be subjected to dependency injection.

Comment: @JeffScottBrown ... Many thanks.I knew something was missing.  So an answer to the question _at-hand_ then would promote `MyApp` to a `Bean` I guess.  I am asked the wrong question.  The examples I've seen so far seem to `.run( MyApp.class )` or just `run()`.  Is there a method then to ensure that the "`runApp(...){ ... }`" code gets executed(?) and also How?

Comment: "Is there a method then to ensure that the "runApp(...){ ... }" code gets executed(?) and also How?" - There are a lot of ways to make sure it gets run.  At what point do you want it to run?

Comment: The question asked what's necessary to let the `runApp(..)` access the `@Inject vehicle` in "**Model A**".  I added a `static Main()` and some labels.  The aim is for label-C to execute `runApp()` and `start` the injected `vehicle`. (per example: [Defining beans](https://docs.micronaut.io/latest/guide/index.html#beans)).  It is clear your input that something is needed in/before the declaration at label-A and perhaps some set-up as indicated at label-B.  In my ignorance, this is the most simple example I could come-up with at the time.